# Is there any way to remove Ads from a "iframe"

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a website, that takes iframes from other website and it has ads on it. Is there any way i could remove those ads?

The iframe url i use(for example):

```
https://openload.co/embed/67YsUGn2BCI/
```

And it has those "popads.net" ads.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't control the webpage content then you probably won't be able to do anything

Comment: Is there really no way? Using `file_get_contents` and `explode`?

Comment: You could proxy that website through a self-hosted script. Create a PHP file that retrieves the other website and edits the HTML to remove the ads before outputting it, then set your iframe's source to that PHP file.

Comment: Rokas, did you find solution?